# What is the equivalent of react context in glimmerjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ember.js, glimmer.js

I've been using react for the past three years and just watched a few talks about ember and glimmer and got interested in glimmer. So excuse my ignorance if the question doesn't make sense.

What will be an equivalent of a `global state / context` in a glimmer app? What I'm looking for is a `@tracked` data which can be accessed deep in the component tree without passing it as `argument` at each level. Think redux without all those ceremonial `action/action-creator/reducer`.

A single global atom with bunch of functions to immutably modify it and re-actively see the change on the component tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are wanting to use services?

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/services/

Services are app level state, and you can use 'injections'  to get access to them deep in your component tree, similar to UseContext.

Also, you may be interested in this: https://www.notion.so/Ember-For-React-Developers-WIP-556a5d343cfb4f8dab1f4d631c05c95b (at http://emberatlas.com, in case the page gets renamed)

There is a section on global state / services / contexts

Note:
Glimmer components are not the default component until ember 3.14

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question the answer is no, at least not yet. Glimmer hasn't made it to v1 yet so maybe open an issue for an enhancement on the glimmer [github page](https://github.com/glimmerjs)

you might also want to look into [glimmer-redux](https://github.com/glimmer-redux/glimmer-redux)

Comment: A service is what the asker in looking for, I think

Comment: Oh, I see it’s not part of glimmer. That is a good solution good job!